# Removing nautilus support for git from rabitvcs in ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu-10.04, rabbitvcs

I have installed rabbitVcs on my machine Ubuntu 11.10, it has support for SVN and git. But with git it's misbehaving in the sense i find these question marks in all the folder which is irritating, how do i control it and can specifically point out that only this is my git repository?
Or how do i just remove support for git from rabbitVCS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I have done git init in my home folder once and it created .git folder there with git configuration, and was treating every folder as a git repository and hence the icons. Deleting that folder solved the problem.